# in excel use checkbox to mark date and time

Tags: excel, date, checkbox, save

In my excel code the goal to use the checkbox to mark the date and time that it was checked. Once it is checked the cell in 1c should display the date and time it was checked. When the excel sheet is closed and reopen the 1c date and time should display the same time and date it should not change.

[picOfCells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7xHQ.png)

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("c1") = Now()`?

Comment: but wont that change every time the sheet is opened and closed?

Comment: Why would it?..

Comment: It looks like this works what if i want to do that for multiple cells. Like the same thing for cells a1: a3 to there corresponding cells in c1:c3